# In 2013 what is the best android phone for development

Tags: android, performance, development-environment

As everyone knows, including Moore, technology doubles every 18 months.  Today, in August of 2013, what is the best UNLOCKED android phone to get for development?  Also, what technical points should be considered when looking at all models.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Would like to limit the discussion to what are good phones for developing apps, including working on the Android OS itself (an open-source project).  Thus, a phone with a majority of features used in apps, without needing to have the best/highest resolution version of those features.

Comment: To All, opinions can be well-informed based on experience.  This question asks people who have experience with Android phones which phone has the best combination of features/price.  If you have worked on an Android phone and do not have a viewpoint then you have **not** learned anything.  I would like to hear from people who have learned from their experience and can share that learning.  Please take this question off hold.  Note, you have the same question in 2010, look at how much the phone world has changed!!

Answer (score 4):

'Best' is a bit subjective. It could be in regards with sheer performance, or it could be more generalized. Nonetheless, I'd personally say the Nexus 4 is the best just because it IS a Nexus device, has pretty good specs, and can be had for an incredibly low $200 off-contract.

That being said, as far as development devices go the Nexus 10 would shine in that category. Without rooting or anything you can achieve simulating various device sizes. See: http://www.androidcentral.com/use-nexus-10-simulate-almost-any-android-device-while-testing-your-app

Over the years I've gone through 6 different Android devices and when it came to development, I didn't have many issues. On Windows machines I found getting drivers was an issue for some but it mostly didn't matter. I currently have a Galaxy S4 now. It's fine for development but I've always felt that since Nexus devices have AOSP ROMs, if you're making your apps to work on AOSP they should be expected to run on non-AOSP devices, since it's all built off that in the first place.